# Keyboard Repair: Both Shift Keys Dead

Tags: repair, button, keyboard, contact

I have an old notebook working perfectly fine. The only issue is that both `shift` keys are **completely dead**:

- [keyboard top view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXNik.jpg)
- [keyboard bottom view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaHw1.jpg)
- [`left shift` key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBzJN.jpg)
- [rubber button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEogy.jpg)

In order to revive them, I've tried the following:

- remove the dirty with compressed air
- clean the electrical contacts with isopropyl alcohol
- directly press the button underneath the key caps

Unfortunately, nothing worked so far.

The only curiosity is that when I press both `shift` keys + another key, in some cases, I get multiple keypresses. Ex:

- [in] `left shift` + `right shift` + `g`
  [out] `g` + `6` (blinking)
- [in] `left shift` + `right shift` + `h`
  [out] `h` + `8` (blinking)

##### Questions

- What could be causing such malfunction?
- What could be done to fix it?

Comment: "Can you repair a keyboard? My answer is NO! Keyboards are cheap and not designed to be disassembled." - http://www.laptoprepair101.com/how-to-disassemble-laptop-keyboard/

Comment: @BruceAbbott Great link. I've been looking for one of this 'how to tutorial' for a while but haven't found it. +1

Answer (score 1):

Maybe liquid got into it causing fatal corrosion in a trace. Maybe it received an impact that caused a crack in the PCB or caused a through-hole plating to fail open. Given enough time and motivation and a bit of equipment it could probably be repaired.

I agree with buying a replacement keyboard if you can possibly find it. I've done that a few times to various computers (Dell, Asus, Acer) and it's cheap, easy and solves the problem.

Comment: > "Maybe liquid got into it causing fatal corrosion in a trace." If anything mechanical caused this malfunction, it must have happened to both `shift` keys. Seems too much coincidence to me ...

Comment: > "Maybe it received an impact" In this case the entire notebook would have received such impact too. IMHO, there are other areas of the notebook that are more delicate and prone to take such damage. But everything else, except both shift keys, are working perfectly fine.

Comment: > "a crack in the PCB" A crack in the PCB could cause the aforementioned `left shift` + `right shift` issue?

Comment: @JeronBaffom being blunt, I'd suggest you buy a replacement so you get a working notebook. Once the new part is installed and running, break open the old part so you can find what's wrong

Comment: It would be easy to answer that question if we  had a schematic of the key matrix. Sometimes the shift keys are connected in parallel so any break in the common connections would do it, though most full size keyboards have different key codes for left and right shift.

Comment: @VictorSouza > "I'd suggest you buy a replacement so you get a working notebook." The notebook is working fine. I can just plug an usb keyboard in it. The point is that it would be much better if I could fix this shift key issue, preferably, if there were an easy and free fix.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany > "It would be easy to answer that question if we had a schematic of the key matrix." Agree, but I doubt Acer would ever post such schematic ...

Comment: @SpehroPefhany > "Sometimes the shift keys are connected in parallel so any break in the common connections would do it" Interesting, didn't know that. Just an additional info: the OS could differentiate which shift key was being pressed (left or right). Even so, do you think it is still possible that these shift keys were connected in parallel?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany > "most full size keyboards have different key codes for left and right shift." Mine is not full size, but the OS could indeed differentiate which shift key were being pressed.

Comment: @VictorSouza > "open the old part so you can find what's wrong" Unfortunately, I'm not an expert on the subject to be able to make such a diagnosis.

Comment: Well there's likely a common line between the two shift keys and maybe some lesser used keys, some or all of which may have also failed. Anyway if  you can't diagnose a simple X-Y matrix of membrane switches when apart, how can you hope to repair it? That's why such repair questions are discouraged here.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany > "some or all of which may have also failed." Only the shift keys are dead. AFAIK, all the rest of the keyboard is working fine.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany > "how can you hope to repair it?" Sometimes there is a quick fix. I'm not sure whether there is a quick fix for this issue, but I'm sure that if I don't look after then I would not find any.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany > "That's why such repair questions are discouraged here." Ok, didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off buying an after market replacement. Those keyboards are practically monolithic parts, hard to repair.

Comment: > "Those keyboards are practically monolithic parts" Agree, at least I've could not find a way open it without breaking it.

Comment: > "You're probably better off buying an after market replacement." Proprietary devices are expensive and hard to find.

Comment: Any idea why this `left shift` + `right shift` issue? I've never seen a keyboard malfunction like this one before.

Comment: Not sure. When membrane keyboards fail, it usually involves an entire row or column of keys

Comment: I looked online for this specific part and found plenty of options relatively cheap. I guess you have to judge for yourself if it's worth the price

Comment: > "When membrane keyboards fail, it usually involves an entire row or column of keys" Interesting, didn't know about that. Let me see if I can guess why: the trace circuits in the membrane form a kind of matrix. Therefore, if one of these traces opened, an entire row or column would be dead. Correct?

Comment: > "When membrane keyboards fail, it usually involves an entire row or column of keys" In this case, is it reasonable to rule out the possibility that a trace circuit got broken?

Comment: @JeronBaffom when you press a key you close the circuit between a row and a column. That's how the keyboard figures out which key you're pressing. Modifier keys like Shift, Alt and Control might be treated differently.